# How to get all rdf file about berlin from dbpedia

Tags: rdf, dbpedia

in this page: http://thedatahub.org/dataset/dbpedia I can find information about dbpedia such as sparql endpoint and so on. Where and how I should ask to get all rdf file where is mention something about berlin ?

Comment: Duplicate of question on answers.semanticweb.com: http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/15095/is-possible-to-get-all-rdf-file-where-is-metion-something-about-berlin. Several relevant comments and answers there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get ***everything*** related to Berlin in RDF you'll probably have to write your own SPARQL (CONSTRUCT) query including regexs, but to get all the triples directly featuring the resource :

http://dbpedia.org/resource/Berlin

you can go to that URL (which will redirect you to http://dbpedia.org/page/Berlin which is *about* Berlin) and at the bottom of the page are links to the data in various formats.

PS. ok, here's a SELECT version for grabbing mentions of the text "berlin" :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?p ?o WHERE { 
   ?s ?p ?o .
   FILTER regex(?o, 'berlin', 'i') 
}
```

That may produce too many results/time out, so you might want to replace ?p with a known property (like abstract, not sure what the dbPedia term is). To get the output as RDF you'd tweak it to something this shape:

```
CONSTRUCT { ?s ?p ?o } WHERE { 
   ?s ?p ?o .
   FILTER regex(?o, 'berlin', 'i') 
}
```

Comment: ok and when I looking for berlin mention in abstract ? Can I construc this select ?

Comment: I don't recommend using that query w/ a regex, you're going to be performing a regex over every literal in dbpedia, that can be very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off either doing what danja suggested w/ downloading the data off the page, or trying

```
describe <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Berlin>
```

or

```
construct { 
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Berlin> ?p ?o .
  ?s ?p2 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Berlin>.
} 
where { 
  { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Berlin> ?p ?o } 
  union 
  { ?s ?p2 <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Berlin> } 
}
```

The latter query should suffice if the results from the describe are insufficient

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at the [examples section](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/OnlineAccess) of the DBPedia documention.